# After creating a new page, filling the page with structure

Tags: pages, editor, customization

I looked 2 days now but I couldn't figure out how this is done:

I created a new page in wordpress. This is easy. Then I see, that I can put content into the page. This is easy too.

But how can I edit the page and add let's say the googlemaps api to it. I know there is a plugin but for some technical reasons I need to use the normal include of google maps. =)

The name of my page is "About". I can't find any about.html or about.php in my wordpress folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a new "physical page" and save it in your theme root folder as a template called something suchlike tpl_aufwind.php like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Aufwind
 *
 *
*/
?>
```

you will need that code above at the very top of the tpl_aufwind.php so that it shows up in wp-admin dashboard >> pages >> Page Attributes (right sidebar) >> Template

[Create Your Own Wordpress Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

your options then if you need to add google maps the normal way is to hardcode it in (or if you know of a plugin where you can use a shortcode try that), but if you are using shortcodes or wish to show more on the page than just the Google Maps api then add a wp loop either above or below your hardcode so at least something on the page can be edited via the admin pages panel